# AWS Cognito redirect mismatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm experiencing an issue with a lightweight VueJS application that is deployed via Docker onto ECS and utilizes a private application load balancer (ALB). I'm using AWS Cognito handler user authentication and have an app client set up as follows:

[image]

The censored part of the callback and sign out URLs is the reference to the internal ALB in EC2.

I have the following Docker env file which is passing environment variables into the docker image when it is built and pushed to AWS ECR:

```
VUE_APP_COGNITO_REDIRECT_URI=https://<ALB_REFERENCE>.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/login/oauth2/code/cognito
VUE_APP_COGNITO_REDIRECT_URI_SIGNOUT=https://<ALB_REFERENCE>.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com/logout
VUE_APP_APP_URL=https://<ALB_REFERENCE>.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com
VUE_APP_COGNITO_USERPOOL_ID=<COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID>
VUE_APP_COGNITO_APP_DOMAIN=<COGNITO_DOMAIN>.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com
VUE_APP_COGNITO_CLIENT_ID=<COGNITO_APP_CLIENT_ID>
```

Then, when I enter the VUE_APP_URL into the browser it does redirect me to the REDIRECT_URI but with the following error:

[image]

The domain in the above error image matches COGNITO_DOMAIN and the `client_id` param matches COGNITO_CLIENT_ID. Based on entering the VUE_APP_URL into the browser, I expect to be redirected to the Cognito login/signup page instead of receiving the error above. What might be the causing the error?

I can provide how the different environment variables are being used in the authentication implementation of the app if it helps, but for brevity of this post I will leave them out for now.

Answer (score 1):

This was an error by me - I needed to stop the ECS cluster task so that it could pick up the new Docker image that I pushed to ECR. Case closed.